# How can I turn off mysql audit log while server is running?

Tags: mysql, space, audit-logging

I do have a highly active server and can't restart it. Long back I have activated the audit log but due to space issue I need to turn it off. Below are my variables;

```
audit_log_buffer_size       | 1048576      |
audit_log_connection_policy | ALL          |
audit_log_current_session   | ON           |
audit_log_exclude_accounts  |              |
audit_log_file              | audit.log    |
audit_log_flush             | OFF          |
audit_log_format            | OLD          |
audit_log_include_accounts  |              |
audit_log_policy            | ALL          |
audit_log_rotate_on_size    | 0            |
audit_log_statement_policy  | ALL          |
audit_log_strategy          | ASYNCHRONOUS |
```

And here is my.cnf

```
plugin-load=audit_log.so
.
.
.
# Audit Log - 
#--------------------------
#audit-log=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT
#audit_log_exclude_accounts=.....
#audit_log_file= /var/log/mysql/mysql_audit_db1.log
.
.
.
```

***Solution:*** 
    After running `UNINSTALL PLUGIN audit_log;` it stopped logging to audit_log file for me. To verify that you can use `SHOW PLUGINS;`

```
mysql> UNINSTALL PLUGIN audit_log; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec) 
mysql> show warnings; 
Warning | 1620 | Plugin is busy and will be uninstalled on shutdown enter code here
```

Comment: UNINSTALL PLUGIN plugin_name;

see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/uninstall-plugin/

Comment: that uninstall plugin link info doesn't sound very dynamic and non-restart

Comment: I ran this command and here is the result. It worked for me. Nomore logging >>>>>>mysql> UNINSTALL PLUGIN audit_log; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>>>>>>>>mysql> show warnings;
 Warning | 1620 | Plugin is busy and will be uninstalled on shutdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT looks commented out, you might use the UNINSTALL PLUGIN command, as written here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-plugin-loading.html#server-plugin-uninstalling

If the FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT is active, you're out of luck, as this is to protect the audit log from on-the-fly disabling.

Comment: Looks like it is installed.
 audit_log                  | ACTIVE   | AUDIT              | audit_log.so | PROPRIETARY |

Comment: Then you can try to uninstall it with the uninstall plugin command. If it does not help, you will have to shut the mysql server down for a moment.